# How to stop the cursor not to jump to new line on pressing the enter key in CK editor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Ck Editor Plugin in one of my project.

Inside the text editor, when I press the enter key, the cursor goes to new line as usual. In my case, I don't need this.When the user press the Enter key, the cursor should remain at the end of the current line. I know it is easy with textarea and I have done that. But in ck editor, it shows nothing when using its blur,focus etc event handlers.

**So how can I Prevent the cursor not to jump to new line after pressing the enter key?**

The TinyMCE Math/Graph Plugin demo link is given below.

http://www.imathas.com/editordemo/demo.html

Comment: what do you want to do when the user press enter?

Comment: when the user press the Enter key, I want the cursor to jump to the end of the current line not to new line. In other words, the cursor should stuck at the end of the line.

Comment: I think @Ibu might be trying to make you think about [usability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usability) with his/her comment. It's often not a good idea to change *familiar* or *expected* behaviour.